# Problema com aplicação Laravel + AdminLTE

Tags: php, laravel, template, binding, laravel-5.1

Meu problema é o seguinte, a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo possui uma listagem de clientes, que utiliza o seguinte código para exibição:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="data-table-clientes" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-xs-1">#</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">CNPJ</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">Razão Social</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">Nome Fantasia</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2">Email</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2"></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php $i = 0 ?>
                        @foreach( $clientes as $cliente )
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{(($clientes->currentPage() - 1 ) * $clientes->perPage() ) + (++$i)}}</td>
                                <td>{{$cliente->cnpj}}</td>
                                <td>{{$cliente->razao_social}}</td>
                                <td>{{$cliente->nome_fantasia}}</td>
                                <td>{{($cliente->email)}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn-sm btn-warning margin" href="{{route('clientes.edit', ['id' => $cliente->id])}}" title="Editar">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{route('clientes.delete', ['id' => $cliente->id])}}" title="Excluir">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!! $clientes->render() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Mas, vez ou outra que a página sofre um `reload` (paginação é um exemplo), o conteúdo fica deformado da seguinte forma e só volta ao normal dando `reload` novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Creio que não seja o `AdminLTE`, pelo fato de eu ter reescrito tudo sem `Laravel` para fins de teste, com mesmo conteúdo e o problema não persistiu.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está aqui:

```
<td>
  <a class="btn-sm btn-warning margin" href="{{route('clientes.edit', ['id' => $cliente->id])}}" title="Editar">
     <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{route('clientes.delete', ['id' => 
  $cliente->id])}}" title="Excluir">
   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

Existe uma maneira mais simplificada de passar o ID do cliente: `{{ route('clientes.edit', $client->id) }}`

```
<td>
  <a class="btn-sm btn-warning margin" href="{{ route('clientes.edit', $client->id) }}" title="Editar">
     <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
   </a>
  <a class="btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('clientes.edit', $client->id) }}" title="Excluir">
   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Ainda apresenta o mesmo problema, mas obrigado pela dica de simplificação. Creio que seja algo na forma como a Blade trabalha, será que indo para a ultima versão resolve?

Comment: Oo! Estranho. Eu uso dessa forma, será que não é essa sua primeira row do número de página? Eu não entendi a necessidade disso, para ser sincero. Por que não exibir o ID do cliente com `$client->id`?

Comment: Se refere à primeira coluna? Eu preciso que listagem siga uma ordem de registros, paginando posso me localizar em número de registros, $client->id ficaria com uma lacuna caso algum registro fosse excluído.